# A good monospace, condensed and open-source typeface?

Tags: website-design, typography, web-fonts

I'm looking for an optimal typeface for report tables that will contain many columns (the reason for condensed).

The reason for monospace is that these reports will contain a lot of numbers and we would like them to be aligned across all the rows.

The reason i need it to be open-source is that we will show these reports inside a web application, so it would be embedded as a web font (@font-face).

I saw [Anka Coder](http://code.google.com/p/anka-coder-fonts/) but I don't like its `0`.

**Update:**

I finally settled for [Open Sans Condensed Light](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed), which has monospaced numbers, so it's good enough for my use case. Thanks everyone for your input!

Comment: you could try your luck with the [Google fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) monospace category, they've got twelve families to choose from. Don't exactly know how-open source they arem though.

Comment: If it’s just numbers and similar you need to have aligned in tables, it’s a font with tabular numbers you want, which does not necessarily be fully monospaced. In many fonts tabular numbers are the default or can be activated as an OpenType feature.

Comment: A little to late for my comment but I think almost all fonts have monospaced numbers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most condensed monospace, open-source font I've found is via [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/M-1m) and is called M+ 1m.

[image: M+ 1m font]

Comment: Though M+ fonts missing ligatures and it looks like they will always be

Answer (score 18):

Another narrow monospace font I've found recently is [Iosevka](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka). It's very clean and legible even on (relatively) low resolutions. And it's completely free and opensource. I really love this font and use it everywhere.

[image: Iosevka sample]

Answer (score 12):

**[Latin Modern Mono](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Latin-Modern-Mono)** is available from FontSquirrel (and also a core font from LaTeX) which is very tight in condensed form.

[image: Latin Modern Mono Light Cond sample at 18pt]

As an additional option, [**Anka Coder**](https://code.google.com/p/anka-coder-fonts/) comes in both Condensed and Narrow widths.

The Narrow version is one of the other narrowest open-source monospace fonts *I* have seen. It runs neck and neck with M+1M for width, but with a more divergent style.

[image: Anka Coder Narrow sample at 18pt]

<sup>p.s. I could have sworn you hadn't mentioned Anka Coder when I read the question, If you had, my apologies for serving it up to you again. At least this gives you the option to see it next to the other options.</sup>

Comment: +1 completely missed the condensed form of Latin modern, nice find.

Comment: I use Latin Modern Mono Condensed a lot for documentation in LaTeX and it works very well — readable even at small sizes, letterforms well distinguished (0/O and 1/l/I). But it's relatively light, so it doesn't sort easily with heavier body fonts.

Comment: I've tried great many mono fonts today, and Latin Modern is the only one I truly like for the application where I need. I mean, there are many great fonts for e.g. code editors, but they all look wrong in my application. Thanks a lot! P. S. The other good one is _Roboto Mono Light_ from Google, it's not a wide font either.

Answer (score 5):

An old truetype font...

http://www.dafont.com/crystal.font

It is a bit odd looking but the digits are very distinctive and easy to tell apart at small sizes.

Answer (score 5):

[Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata) now has plenty of different widths apart from regular width:

- SemiCondensed, Condensed, ExtraCondensed, UltraCondensed
- SemiExpanded, Expanded, ExtraExpanded, UltraExpanded

Answer (score 4):

Check out this site. https://www.programmingfonts.org/

The most condensed is Quinze, but it may be too much. I found glyphs were touching each other in some cases. Then there is sudo, wich works great with line-height 1.0 and is an OK compromise if you really want to save space.

Many fonts are as condensed as Iosevka: M+, Terminus, Inconsolata Regular, etc...

I found that the best way to compare widths was by typing a ruler of ten sets of 0-9 digits on the top and a second one below that for the tenths.

Comment: I really appreciate the tip to determine which font is wider.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest NK57 Monospace Condensed Extrabold, by Ray Larabie.

- [Typodermic Fonts](https://typodermicfonts.com/nk57-monospace/)

[image]

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for your contribution. While your answer is technically correct, could you [edit] it to include, the reasons why you think it's a good match, a link to the font and maybe an image showing the font? Thanks! Feel free to keep contributing, browse the site, leave more answers and maybe ask a question of your own.

Comment: That's a pretty good one, thank you for sharing this, Victor!

Answer (score 2):

I personally suggest [Meslo LG](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font)

> Meslo LG is a customized version of Apple’s Menlo-Regular font
>   (which is a customized Bitstream Vera Sans Mono).

I like the dotted zero version

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: The best narrow mono font available today (July 2023) in Google Fonts is *Nanu Gothic Coding***

- GitHub repo https://github.com/emersion/nanum-gothic-coding
- Google Fonts https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nanum+Gothic+Coding

*Nanum Gothic Coding is a contemporary monospaced sans-serif typeface with a warm touch, and it is expertly hinted for screen use. It is part of the Nanum fonts (나눔글꼴) – a set of high quality Unicode fonts designed especially for the Korean-language script “Hangeul” that also support Latin. Designed by Sandoll Communications (산돌 커뮤니케이션) and Fontrix (폰트릭스,) and published by Naver (네이버.)*

**Why this is the best**

- It's elegant, but not too striking to be distracting
- Its line height is very close to Arial or Helvetica, i.e. unlike many nice fonts that are just too blocky and disproportionately tall, i.e. JetBrains Mono or Roboto Mono
- Line weight is a bit thinner than Arial or Helvetica, great for dense "wall of numbers" reports

**Comparison of all monospace Google Fonts**

Notice the line length, and how precise or messy the special characters are in some fonts.

[image: monospace Google Fonts]

Answer (score 0):

"American Typewriter" is not strictly monospace, but on MS Powerpoint it gives an impression of a monospace, and useful for distinguishing code/commands from the rest of text.
Consolas takes more width, otherwise it would have been perfect.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).